# QuickBooks Automation

Tags: command-line, quickbooks

Does anyone know of any commandline switches that can be used with QuickBooks?

In particular, I am looking for a way to *restore* a company file without using the menu in QuickBooks.

I've searched all over the internet and not found anything at all.

**after several days have passed without responses**

Well, I suppose there are no such thing as commandline switches.  What about a COM interface - is that possible?  Maybe someone who knows for certain can say there is no such thing as commandline interaction with quickbooks?  That would be an answer, after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up writing an autohotkey script that manipulated the alt+menu commands.  Hacky, but it works.